# WordPress Instance always link to localhost:8080 which not work

Tags: wordpress, port

i use on my mac the built-in web server "Apache". I create a local folder where all my wordpress websites are stored.

This is an example of one of my websites:
~/Users/username/Workspace/WordPress/website1/wp-content/themes/themes-name

When i wan to open the WP in browser i have to go to:
http://localhost/WordPress/website1/

For a few days now, when you click on the navigation point, the port :8080 is always added, with the message that the website cannot be reached. If I delete the port in the URL it works again, but how can I set it so that it doesn't add the port to me at all?

I don't use Docker.

My Mac shut down because I forgot to plug in the cable. After switching on it started with the port. Unfortunately I have no idea where to look.

I'm very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Local Flywheel. (don't confuse it with their similarly named hosting service, which is paid)

https://localwp.com/ (free with everything you need, paid plan has some extras)

It is:

- created for wordpress
- beginner friendly
- has built in hot-reloading
- uses containers
- super easy site migration
- has debugging included

You will have the added benefit of stuff less likely conflicting between a local flywheel installation and live, compared to a mac installation and live.